# Cypress Webpack Compilation Error create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, cypress

```
const findWebpack = require('find-webpack');
const injectDevServer = require('@cypress/react/plugins/react-scripts');
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // const webpack = require('./webpack.config.js');
  // find the Webpack config used by react-scripts
  const webpackOptions = findWebpack.getWebpackOptions();

  if (!webpackOptions) {
    throw new Error('Could not find Webpack in this project ');
  }

  // if we just pass webpackOptions to the preprocessor
  // it won't work - because react-scripts by default
  // includes plugins that split specs into chunks, etc.
  // https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-webpack-preprocessor/issues/31

  // solution 1
  // blunt: delete entire optimization object
  // delete webpackOptions.optimization

  // solution 2
  // use a module that carefully removes only plugins
  // that we found to be breaking the bundling
  // https://github.com/bahmutov/find-webpack
  const cleanOptions = {
    reactScripts: true,
  };

  findWebpack.cleanForCypress(cleanOptions, webpackOptions);

  const options = {
    webpackOptions,
    watchOptions: {},
  };

  injectDevServer(on, config);
  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));
  return config;
};
```

Hi, after migration from cypress 9.5.4 to 10.11.0 I have a lot of Webpack Compilation Errors that i didnt have before. Some of them I solved with "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": but some of them I couldnt resolve. Can you help me with the problem on screen?[Webpack compilation error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dg0i.png)

Comment: Can you please provide your code in the post as a code sample, not as an image? So we can read your code easily :)

Comment: Yes, please. I did it)

Comment: @annaswan Having the same problem. Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. I reviewed all my commits and found the one after each problem appeared. I dont know why, but Сypress didnt like simple SPLIT() function. So, I change some lines of my code and it works know